# Op-amp output cannot reach Vcc

Tags: operational-amplifier

I am trying to build an op-amp circuit for a Hall effect sensor. The Hall effect sensor has an output range of 2.01V to 2.87V, and is fed to the *Vin* of the op-amp circuit below. The output *V_out* range is measured to be 3.71V to 0.81V. The 3.71V is largely off from calculations, which should be near 4.8V. The op-amp unit is a **MCP602**, which should give rail-to-rail output.

[image]

Using the same **MCP602** op-amp as a comparator, I still get an output of only 3.71V. Swaping the op-amp for a **LM358** unit, I still get a maximum output voltage of about 3.70V.

What could be the problem? Is it possible that all the op-amps I purchased are all faulty?

Comment: Where did you  get the 'MCP602' from?

Comment: Yeah, but the MCP602 doesn't have rail-to-rail input.  See `Vcmr` in its datasheet.  You might have better luck with a non-inverting configuration for this application.

Comment: @SteKulov But that is an inverting op-amp circuit so both inputs always have 2.5V - well within common mode input range. However the non-inverting config you suggest is subject to limited common mode range.

Comment: @Justme Ah, true.  My bad.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I tested your circuit with an a genuine MCP602 (purchased from [Element14](https://nz.element14.com/)) and an LM358. With Vin grounded the MCP602's output was 4.99 V, and the LM358 was 3.72 V. With Vin connected to +5 V the MCP602's output was 0 V, and the LM358 was 0.52 V.

Conclusion:- your 'MCP602' is a fake.